# Is it unprofessional to ask for a laptop loan that i will use for work

Tags: salary

I was considering to ask from my boss for 2 years even though he wasn't offering it. He outsourced his Customer Service to our country and he was nice all the time however with very few benefits, and anything that he may offer may be changed by him without prior notice. Just like paid- time off. He may give us leave pay but no assurance. It depends on his move. Regarding benefits, I have raised this with him, where we need to streamline employees' benefits and guidelines but he just brushed it off. Fine, his call maybe he is not ready yet. If I would buy the laptop by myself I guess it's fine but I thought I should ask since I have been using my old laptop for this work only and other things that I do, side gigs, personal - I use a different laptop. Now, I believe it's due for retirement and I need an upgrade. I want it to be as simple as he is loaning me a computer an I repay it in 2 mos without interest but if its going to look unprofessional, I won't. thanks for your help.

Comment: I also recommend Workplace. OP is asking how to behave professionally (in a situation where the employer may be deviating from professional norms).

Comment: @keshlam But an answer in Workplace could address what are the normal practices in OP's country/industry and *how* to approach asking the employer.

Comment: You use it only for this work? Then it is the boss's problem. You cannot take as many calls because the laptop is slow? Not your problem - your boss says to use the old laptop so use the old laptop. It is very rare to spend more than a few bucks of *your own* money for equipment you will only use *at work*.

Comment: And this is why we don't cross-post.

Comment: Are you telling us that it depends on your boss' mood whether or not you get paid for time off? That's a huge problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a laptop for work, and you don't have one, then your company should supply one. Asking for one isn't unprofessional at all. Obviously that laptop could only be used for work.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is "what does your contract say". Your contract should say whether you have to provide a computer for work, or if your company provides it. If nothing is aid then it is normal for your company to provide you with all the tools you need to do your job, including a computer. If you don't have a contract then anything said in writing on the matter will do instead.

Whatever the contract says, that is what you should do. If the company is expected to provide one, ask for a new one. If you are expected to, then go out an get the one you need to do your job. If the contract doesn't say you need a separate computer, then the one you use for other work will do the trick, unless there is something in your contract saying they can look at or take possession of your computer.